# Accessing Information From Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am binding data to a drop down list, and I want to capture both the 1st element as well as the second element.  However, both methods that I tried only capture the first element?  Can someone show me how to remedy?

**This is how I bind to my Drop Down**

```
protected void BindDropDown()
{
  var itemandprice = new List<ListItem>
  {
    new ListItem("Flannel Pajamas", "9"),
    new ListItem("Fleece Jacket", "30"),
    new ListItem("Flannel Shirt", "40")
  }

  this.dropdownlist123.DataSource = itemandprice;
  this.dropdownlist123.DataBind();
}
```

**Selected Index Change Event**

```
protected void dropdownlist123_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.txtOne.Text = dropdownlist123.SelectedValue;
  this.txtTwo.Text = dropdownlist123.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

BOTH text boxes have the value "Flannel Pajamas" in it instead of what I am after which would be Flannel Pajamas and 9

What do I need to do in order to capture both elements?

**EDIT 1**
Per @Alex Krups suggestion I attempted this syntax, but that gives me the same output as my syntax above

```
this.txtOne.Text = dropdownlist123.SelectedItem.Value;
this.txtTwo.Text = dropdownlist123.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the DataTextField and DataValueField for your DropDownList.

Please try this:

```
this.DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
this.DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value"; 
this.DropDownList1.DataSource = itemandprice;
this.DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Hope this help~

Comment: That was it, THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.txtOne.Text = dropdownlist123.SelectedItem.Value;
this.txtTwo.Text = dropdownlist123.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: same returned results as I have.